# How to rollback to a transaction made by django default, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django

so I have a django app using MySQL database, the client asked for some database records deletions, and one of our developers did the deletions manually from the MySQL console, now I'm trying to recover it to the previous state, I don't have any backups, I read that django does transactions automatically by default,so I want to know how can I rollback to one of these transactions.

I already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356566/how-can-i-roll-back-my-last-delete-command-in-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/display-open-transactions-in-mysql), none of them helped me.

Comment: There is a setting in Django to wrap views in transactions. By default that is turned off. But even if it is on, if the view ends, then the changes are commited.

Comment: Furthermore if the deletions are done manually, it is likely these are not wrapped in a transaction in the first place, since otherwise, you would not see the changes in the app itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so i can't rollback this disaster?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible no.